# Is there a Japanese equivalent for "just" in this context?

Tags: translation

I want to say something along the lines of "I don't like A, I **just** like B" but am unsure of how to translate the word "just" when used in this way in English. The first part of the sentence is easy enough, and I know that I can simplify the expression by saying it as, 「私はAが好きではありません。Bが好きです。」Is there something I can use in Japanese to convey that nuance?

EDIT: An example sentence that might help explain the usage I'm going for is, "I'm not a fan of the band, I **just** like being around people."

EDIT2: Forgot that there are separate implications between the two just's that I have provided. The second one is what I was going for.

Comment: The 'just' in "I don't like A, I just like B" is very different from the 'just' in "I just like being around people", and you should not expect to use the same Japanese word for both of them. Hint: the first 'just' means 'only' and the second 'just' means 'simply'.

Comment: You're right! Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

「なのではなく」がおすすめです。

私はAが好きなのではなく、Bが好きなのです。

これに「だけ」を付け足したら、よりBが好きだという事実が強調されます。

私はAが好きなのではなく、Bが好きなだけです。

「、」で区切って続けて書くことで、AとBの対比が強く表現されるので、一続きに書いたほうが、意図は示しやすいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you can usually translate *just* as だけ, and it's placed after what it marks, instead of before. However, I don't think you can use it in every possible situation where you'd say *just* in English.

Your sentence would be:

> 私はAが好きではありません。Bだけが好きです。

The example you added in your edit is a bit more complex. This is how I'd say it in Japanese, but if you're still beginning I wouldn't try to understand a sentence like this.

> バンドのファンではありません。人が多いところが好きなだけです。

Edit: for you to understand how だけ works better, let's say it becomes kind of part of the word it follows. If B had to be followed by が, to say *just B* you add だけ after B, and that becomes a new noun, that can be followed by が as well. You just have to insert it there. Don't think of it as an adverb or try to compare it to *just* in English, because it's actually simpler, but may seem difficult if you try to use it the same way.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thank you for the response! I think I see how だけ is used from your examples. I'm definitely still a beginner when it comes to sentence construction, so it's difficult to completely remove myself from my English-speaking tendencies and expectation for congruency between the two languages.

Comment: I understand that, but don't worry about it. You'll get used to the Japanese way of thinking as you study grammar. Good luck!

Comment: Nothing wrong with this answer, but I think the first sentence sounds a bit brusk in this context. More natural/common phrasing would be to use というより:  `バンドのファンというより（は/も）、人が集まるところが好き（なだけ）です。`